# What will be the height if the body ascends a slope with a some speed against frictional force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass-energy

A body ascends a slope with a some speed. If some energy is lost due to friction, the height to which the body rise is.

I referred some books and came to know
Work done in moving up a body on a rough incline is given as W= mg(sin theta + x cos theta)S
Where x is frictional force ,S is displacement

But in this case mass is not given is there any way to find mass. Inclined angle is also not given!!

Comment: According to what you've stated, the body ascends at a constant speed. That means it never stops. It will keep going forever. You need to clarify this by taking a closer look at the problem statement.

Comment: A body ascends a slope with a speed of 10ms^-1. If 105 J of energy of the body is lost due to friction , the height to which the body will rise is  (take g =10ms^-2).  This is the actual question.

Comment: In my opinion, the author of the question has a gift for confusing students.

Comment: @Inquisitive I've noticed this on a huge number of closed homework questions too. My general impression is that all textbooks from India are terrible. I want to make a custom close message that just says, "burn that book and just buy a standard US textbook".

Comment: @knzhou It's incredibly difficult to write a high-quality calculus, physics, engineering, etc., textbook. It would take a small team years to write one. Here is a college calculus textbook that I think was FANTASTIC in its day, "Calculus with Analytic Geometry, 2nd Edition", by Howard Anton. I used it back in 1986. It was terrific. The illustrations were wonderfully instructive.

Comment: @Inquisitive Yeah, totally agreed. I was born way after these things, but I still learned physics from a book from the 80's, an old edition of Halliday and Resnick. It's good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Energy before equals:

$$m*g*h_o + \frac{1}{2}mv_o^2$$

Energy after equals:

$$m*g*h_f + \frac{1}{2}mv_f^2 + 105J$$

After equating:

$$m*g*h_o + \frac{1}{2}mv_o^2 = m*g*h_f + \frac{1}{2}mv_f^2 + 105J$$

Watch your units!

Comment: What is v1,v2 ,h1 and h2?

Comment: @AUmarMukthar Better?

Comment: Seems to be ok. But still confusing. I will discuss with my senior staffs. Thanks for your support